# set up Facebook Pixel only for production in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, facebook, environment-variables

I am using React as my front-end (and Rails as my back-end).

I am setting up the Facebook Pixel Events Manager to track my Facebook ads on my website.

So I added this script to my public/index.html:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'MYID');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=MYID&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

and in my React Components I added this callback function anytime a button is clicked and raise an event:

`() => fbq('track', 'MyEvent');`

It seems to work, although I need my pixels to fire only in production. I can't access `process.env.NODE_ENV` in `public/index.html`.

What can I do to have this code used only in production ?

Comment: That file is delivered as is. To add a pixel only in production you'd need to have a separate index file you use in the production build, or add that code into a component that has access to the env, like in your footer component.

Comment: thank you for your help @Dvid Silva ! OK so I have a component that wraps my entire app; Should I put this code in my `ComponentDidMount()` method ? 
If I want to use a separate index file, how can I do that ? create another entry point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Dvid Silva and @Russ Brown, I finaly went with the following solution: create two separate index.html files: `dev-index.html` and `prod-index.html`

in my `config/path.js`:

```
module.exports = {
#[...]
  appHtml: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? resolveApp('public/prod-index.html') : resolveApp('public/dev-index.html'),
#[...]
};
```

Both index files are identical except the production one has the Facebook Pixel inside its `<head>` tag.

Comment: but how do you add  this file from `module.exports`? How does it look your html file where you import this condition?

Answer (score 1):

In most of my simple apps I choose to manage this by printing a JS variable into the html page. My prefer goto is Handlebars and I'll inject a config object into the header that will contain something like.

```
    <script type="application/javascript">
      var CONFIG = {
        fbPixel: '{{ fbPixel }}'
      }
    </script>
```

The `fbPixel` comes from a config file and is only populated in staging and production environments. In development it's undefined/empty. Quick and simple to setup. In my more complicated apps I still basically do the same thing, but use a helper function in the middle for validation and allowing of default options.

Comment: Thank you for your help Russ Brown! that's interesting. I actually went with @Dvid Silva's solution that is creating to different entry points for dev and prod env. But This seems to be working as well !

Comment: @Russ Brown, but `'{{ fbPixel }}'` is a variable that you import? How to you import in html file the config?

Comment: In my case, I'm using nodeJs to render the page so server-side Javascript is responsible for that. Other times I use react-helmet and the variable comes from javascript variables injected into the header via the backend.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution: if you use git;
checkout from your "master" branch, and create a new branch called "dev":

```
git checkout -b dev
```

then on your "master" branch, reserved for production, inject the pixel code base. Checkout again to your dev branch and work there.
When you want to push new features into production, merge "dev" into "master",  while keeping 2 versions of the file `index.html`